# Loop insert date Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, calendar

Calendar1, Calendar2 are declared at the beginning of class.

and I use them with 2 datepicker dialog. Now I'm inserting a record each month between Calendar1 and Calendar2, but the insertion of the record begins the month following the month in Calendar1 chosen. For example, if I choose 01/01/2014 in Calendar1 records are inserted from 01/02/2014

```
public void date(View v){
SQLiteDatabase db = ....;
ContentValues cv = ....;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
for(int i=0; calendar1.getTime().before(calendar2.getTime()); i++) {

    calendar1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

        if (calendar1.getTime().before(calendar2.getTime())) {
        // insert calendar1 into db DB
String strDate = sdf.format(calendar1.getTime() );
        cv.put(tTable.DATE, strDate);
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean. Some sample input, expected output and actual output would really help. Oh, and more code than just the start of the loop... *how* are you inserting `calendar1`?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as you do not use the iterating variable i you can use a simple while-loop.

```
while(calendar1.currentTimeMillis() < calenader2.currentTimeMillis()) {
    // insert into the database

    calendar1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
```

If you have to add a month the first time before adding the entry to the db simply do it before the loop as you can avoid if-statements this way.
I did not check the code as I currently do not have an IDE but the general approach should work.